# write a query to insert into a identity column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have used identity key in a column of a table like

```
create table test(testid int identity(1,1),testname varchar(10))
```

and then I have inserted 2 rows like

```
Insert into test(testname) values('c')
Insert into test(testname) values('c#')
```

Now,My table contains like below:

```
1     c    
2     c#
```

But,I want insert another row into this table test like
5 c++

So,My table will contain like

```
1       c   
2       c#  
5      c++
```

So,please send me the output as soon as possible.Help me please.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: Do you really need the `testid` column to be `identity` if you have the need to insert arbitrary values into it?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [SET IDENTITY_INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259221.aspx):

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT test ON;

Insert into test(testid, testname)values(5, 'c++');

SET IDENTITY_INSERT test OFF;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/81ea0/4).

Answer (score 1):

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT test ON

INSERT test (testid , testname)
VALUES (5, 'c++')

SET IDENTITY_INSERT test OFF
```